# MySQL To Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, mysql

Say, I have a mysql table with columns like:

```
f_name, l_name, score1, score2, score 3
```

Then I want to create a PHP Associatiove Array from a query to get something like:

```
$array = ('name1'=>65, 'name2'=>45, 'anothername'=>23);
```

the scores e.g `65` is obtained by adding `score1`, `score2` and `score3` and name is obtained from `f_name` and `l_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all what format of array you have specified is single dimension associative array.

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FNAME,' ',LNAME) AS NAMES, 
      SCORE1+SCORE2+SCORE3 AS SUMS FROM EXAMPLE WHERE UID=1;
```

This query will produce result with two columns - NAMES and SUMS which can then be used to create an associative array through php.